# Gstreamer - mp4 generated by 'mp4mux' plays too fast and is not seekable

Tags: video, gstreamer, mp4

I'm saving a MP4 video file out of a H264 stream, generated with the raspivid command (I'm using the Raspberry's camera). The problem I've seen is that some video players can't handle the MP4 file correctly. I've tried Windows Media Player, and the Android-Chrome stock browser (the videos are intended to be played within a webapp) and in both videos are playing very fast (maybe 20x of normal speed), and I can't seek them.

The only player where it works well is VLC, there I've no problems, I can seek and it plays at the correct framerate.

The pipeline:

```
fdsrc,
! video/x-h264,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1,profile=main,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au
! h264parse
! mp4mux faststart=true
! filesink location=test.mp4
```

I've tried to set the `faststart` parameter to true, but it doesn't fix my problem. What else could I try?

Comment: How do you stop your recording? Is this an application or is it done via gst-launch line?

Comment: @thiagoss At the moment I just press Control+C. As far as I've read in the docs, an EOS event is sent to Gstreamer when the stream is interrupted.

Comment: If this is a gst-launch command, that only happens if the `-e` flag is specified.